# Layout with ArrayAdapter and other widget

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-arrayadapter

I've code simple xml layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ARRAYADAPTER" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+listview/lw"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

<Button 
    android:id="@+button/b1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="NEXT"
    android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and set an array adapter inside the list view. When i launch this app, buttod doesn't appear.
What i want to do is divide the layout in three parts: 
-textview on top
-the adapter in the middle (with scrolling)
-the button (or more than one) to bottom.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ListView declaration to:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+listview/lw"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

and set your Button height to `wrap_content`.

This will tell the ListView to take up the remaining space not taken by the TextView and Button.

Answer (score 2):

I think your Button is taking all the space because of `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, try `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: it doesn't take any space, because i can't see it! But this was another bug of my interface, thanks :)

Comment: @giozh anyway that is not correct, you must change that. Are you sure all those paddings are not taking up all the space? What is the XML for "@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
"@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
"@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
"@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

Comment: yes i've change that!
The xml you asking for was autogenerated by eclipse

Comment: @giozh Eclipse generating that kind of padding? I see, you are using the visual editor... delete those paddings!